# on c# MAUI The <TabBar> stop working if I call Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Notificaciones"); from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, android, maui, tabbar

I'm working on one c# MAUI App on the AppShell.xaml file I have a TabBar with 4 Tab:

```
<TabBar> 
    <Tab Title="Saldo"
        Icon="Cat.png">
        <ShellContent
        Route="Saldo" 
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Saldo}"
        />
   </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Pontos" 
        Icon="dog.png">
        <ShellContent
        Route="Pontos"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Pontos}"
        />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Postos"
        Icon="mapa.png">
        <ShellContent
        Route="Postos" 
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Postos}"
        />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Notificaciones"
        Icon="elephant.png">
        <ShellContent
        Route="Notificaciones"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Notificaciones}"
         />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

All work fine but the problem are when I receive a notification I try to open the Notifications from the App.xaml.cs and work but after this the 4 tabs stop navigating

```
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Notificaciones");
    };
```

if I use the same code Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Notificaciones"); from inside of any of the 4 pages all continue working, I read the Xamarin.Forms Shell navigation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) and try all the possible options like "Notificaciones" ; "/Notificaciones" ; "//Notificaciones" ; "///Notificaciones" and or don't go to "Notificaciones" or go and stop working the 4 Tab.

I try too replace the <TabBar> for <FlyoutItem Route="Home"> and use the address  "//Home/Notificaciones" but are always the same problem.

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: Not sure if notification handler is on MainThread. Try `MainThread.Dispatch(() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Notificationes");` Or perhaps `///Notificationes`.

Answer (score 2):

First, change the Shell XAML.

```
 ... 
 <Tab Title="Notificaciones"
    Route="Notificaciones" << route goes here
    Icon="elephant.png">
    <ShellContent
    //Route="Notificaciones" << remove this
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Notificaciones}"
     />
</Tab>
```

Second, change navigation to:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///Notificaciones");
```

Edit:

To clarify, You need to route your tabs. Besides everything else, everyone reading it will know what you are trying to do.

And to navigate to a tab you have to use triple slash. Each tab has its own navigation stack, and you can switch from one to another like that. If you do not do triple, pages will go over your current navigation stack.

This is not bad actually. Sometimes this is something I do on purpose.
But in your case I am 99.99% sure that you are trying to actually select the other tab.